# How to change caption on Search button in ActiveScaffold Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, activescaffold

How to change caption on Search button in ActiveScaffold Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `_search.html.erb` partial by importing it from `AS/frontend/views/default/` into your corresponding views folder and adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, copy that `AS/frontend/views/default/_search.html.erb` partial into your `/app/views/active_scaffold_overrides/` folder, then edit the Search button text, and the updated partial will be used for all ActiveScaffold views in your app.